# Create a SAS Token with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, authorization, sas-token

I would like to be able to create a SAS Token on a Datalake folder in a **very specific manner** using Powershell. I am able to create the SAS Token in the Azure Portal and cannot find a way to create it exactly like that in Powershell.

The SAS Token has to fullfill these conditons:

- Permit access to a Datalake directory
- Use an Access Policy
- The Access Policy does **not** provide Start Time or Expiry Time
- The Access Policy does **not** provide Permissions
- The SAS Token itself provides Start Time and Expiry Time
- The SAS Token itself provides Permission

I used the existing storage account "gfcssa002t" and created a Datalake container "datalake".
Within this container I created a the folder structure "basefolder/testfolder" and uploaded a file "testfile.png":
[image: Screenshot 1]

In the next step I created an Access Policy "testpolicy" with **no permission**, **no start time** and **no exiry time**:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Now I was able to start generating a SAS Token for the folder "basefolder/testfolder":
[image: Screenshot 3]

I generated a SAS Token using Account Key signing (key1), the Access Policy "testpolicy", 5 Permissions (Read, Add, Create, Write, List), Start Time "01.01.2023 00:00:00" and Expiry Time "01.01.2024 00:00:00":
[image: Screenshot 4]

I copied the generated SAS Token URI, inserted "/testfile.png" just behind the part "/datalake/basefolder/testfolder" within the URI, opened a new private Firefox window and inserted this URI:
[image: Screenshot 5]

So, the SAS Token worked the way I expected.

Now I tried to do the same generation of SAS Token by Powershell. Unfortunatly it is not that easy to find out which cmdlet to use. For me it seemed the best to use the cmdlet `New-AzStorageBlobSASToken` ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageblobsastoken?view=azps-9.3.0)) using the code:

```
$accountname="gfcssa0002t"
$accountkey="<.. key ..>"

$containername="datalake"
$blob="basefolder/testfolder"
$policy="testpolicy"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
    -Context $ctx `
    -Container $containername `
    -Blob $blob `
    -Policy $policy `
    -Protocol HttpsOnly `
    -FullUri
```

But this one only works if you define at least Permissions for the Access Policy "testpolicy".
If I do not define Permission, Start Time, Expiry Time I get the error

```
New-AzStorageBlobSASToken : Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.
Parametername: accessPolicy
In C:\Users\...\Projects\Create SAS token.ps1:10 Zeichen:1
+ New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzStorageBlobSASToken], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageBlobSasTokenCommand
```

The same error occurs, when I add Start Time and Expiry Time to the cmdlet:

```
$accountname="gfcssa0002t"
$accountkey="<.. key ..>"

$containername="datalake"
$blob="basefolder/testfolder"
$policy="testpolicy"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
    -Context $ctx `
    -Container $containername `
    -Blob $blob `
    -Policy $policy `
    -Protocol HttpsOnly `
    -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) `
    -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddDays(10) `
    -FullUri
```

And if I try to use the parameter "Permission":

```
$accountname="gfcssa0002t"
$accountkey="<.. key ..>"

$containername="datalake"
$blob="basefolder/testfolder"
$policy="testpolicy"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
    -Context $ctx `
    -Container $containername `
    -Blob $blob `
    -Policy $policy `
    -Protocol HttpsOnly `
    -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) `
    -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddDays(10) `
    -Permission racwl `
    -FullUri
```

The error changes to:

```
New-AzStorageBlobSASToken : Der Parametersatz kann mit den angegebenen benannten Parametern nicht aufgelöst werden.
In C:\Users\...\Projects\Create SAS token.ps1:10 Zeichen:1
+ New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzStorageBlobSASToken], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageBlobSasTokenCommand
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageblobsastoken?view=azps-9.3.0) of the cmdlet there seems to be no valid set of parameters to use an Access Policy, Start Time, Expiry Time and Permission together.

And that's the point where I ran out of ideas.
**How do I achieve the generation of the exact same kind of SAS Token I was able to create with Azure Portal?**

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Access Policy with no Start Time or Expiry Time and permissions:

[image]

When I tried to generate the **SAS Token** I got the same error as below:

```
$accountname="adlsgen2549"
$accountkey="AccountKey"
$containername="datalake"
$blob="basefolder/testfolder"
$policy="testpolicy"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
 New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
   -Context $ctx `
   -Container $containername `
   -Blob $blob `
   -Policy $policy `
   -FullUri
```

[image]

**Note** that: While generating the SAS Token in PowerShell, the Access policy must be predefined with the required permissions like below:

[image]

The  `StartTime` ,`ExpiryTime` ,`Permission` parameters are applicable for the generated SAS token not for the Stored Access Policy:

```
$accountname="adlsgen2549"
$accountkey="AccountKey"
$containername="datalake"
$blob="basefolder/testfolder"
$policy="testpolicy"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
    -Context $ctx `
    -Container $containername `
    -Blob $blob `
    -Policy $policy `
    -Protocol HttpsOnly `
    -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) `
    -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddDays(10) `
    -Permission racwl `
    -FullUri
```

[image]

***I am able to access the blob successfully like below:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your investigation! Even if I create the testpolicy using no start or expiry time but permissions, your code ends up with an error exactly as it was in my question. I have to omit both permission and expirytime parameters, then it works. But then its useless.

Comment: The working of the script is by default and to generate the SAS token based on your requirements you can use Azure Portal only.

Comment: But you wrote that your script worked? I'm confused now. What powershell version are you working with? The output of my `$PSVersionTable is: 5.1.19041.1682

Comment: My PowerShell version is 5.1.22621.963

Comment: My script worked when I added permissions to the testpolicy while creating it.